# Pinvoking not copying entire string

Tags: c#, class, pinvoke

I have a C++ native dll where a structure is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
int x;
int y;
unsigned short* orange;
}SET_PROFILE;
```

And a function in the C++ dll as:

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) void modifyClass(SET_PROFILE** input)
{
    *input = &globPro;  
}
```

where globPro is a global object of type SET_PROFILE and its member orange is "ABC".

I have redefined this structure on the C# side as a class:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class SET_PROFILE
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public String orange;
}
```

and pinvoking the function:

```
[DllImport("Project2.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern void modifyClass(out IntPtr input);
```

When I call this function and then marhal it back to the structure:

```
IntPtr classPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
classPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SET_PROFILE)));
modifyClass(out classPtr);
profile1 = (SET_PROFILE)Marshal.PtrToStructure(classPtr, typeof(SET_PROFILE));
```

Now, profile1's orange meber just has "A" instead of "ABC". It has something to do with how it's copied using pointers. I can't modify the C++ function however.
Is it because I used a string as the member of the C# class instead of unsigned short[]. I tried that too but failed.

Comment: It is a Unicode string, the default marshaling assumes `char*`.  Which is why you get just the single letter, there's an extra binary zero after the 'A'.  Use CharSet = CharSet.Unicode or Marshal.PtrToStringUni().

Comment: Thanks. I edited the dll import to include CharSet = CharSet.Unicode but it still shows a single letter. I cant use Marshal.PtrToStringUni() because I am dealing with the class as a whole and not just the string member of it.

Comment: You are doing this wrong. You should copy the value of the struct into the caller's variable, passed by reference. You should not return a pointer to a global variable in the DLL. And if you ever need to return a pointer, do just that. As the return value. I don't think you fully understand what you are doing. I'd like to help you understand.

Comment: I partly got what you said. What's wrong with getting a pointer to a global var in the dll? I cant return a pointer because the method signature is void, and I can't modify anything on the C++ side.
Also, isn't Marshal.PtrToStructure copying the value of the global struct pointed to by the IntPtr var into the object?

Comment: Why do you want to use global variables? They are evil. Try from multiple threads. Are you 100% sure that you are not allowed to write any C++ code at all?

Comment: I can add new C++ files but I can't modify the existing C++ files.

Comment: So the code you have already includes this global variable which is exposed in this way? Btw, unless you write @DavidHeffernan, I don't get notified of the comments

Comment: That's right @DavidHeffernan The global var is already declared in that C++ file.

Comment: It would still be easier to copy the struct in the C++ code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class SET_PROFILE
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public System.IntPtr orange;    
    public string OrangeString { get { return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(orange); } }
}
```

Comment: Here, is orangeString member a property?

Comment: Nice. It worked. So using an IntPtr, u got it point to the location when it was in c++ and then on the C# side, orangestring property marshals that to a string?

Comment: Also, here the size taken by this class will be 4 bytes more than the C++ structure because of IntPtr?

Comment: Are you running in 64 bit?  If so, then the System.IntPtr will be 8 bytes and it's possible the library is 32 bit and thus 4 bytes.